# Randomize file(image) in php

Tags: php

I have this code:

```
if (file_exists("cdcovers/$artist_name.jpg"))
{
    $fileName = "$artist_name.jpg";
} else {
    $fileName = "logo.png";
}
```

Is it possible to randomize this file:

```
$fileName = "$artist_name.jpg";
```

when there are several different images from the artist?

Comment: What is the naming scheme for the images when there are multiple images related to the same artist? Is there an associated database relating the artists to the images?

Answer (score 0):

YOu can probably add time to make unique filename.

```
$array = explode('.', $fileName );
$fileName=$array[0];
$fileExt=$array[1];
$newfile=$fileName."_".time().".".$fileExt;
```

Comment: Aman i dont meant to randomize by time, that i have done, i meant per example $artist_name.jpg", to be one time this: u2.jpg, one time u2_new.jpg. maybe i did not explain good.

Comment: I want to echo a different image each time.

Comment: That is what i have done, above code will output different filename every time. You can also do, if file exits you can versions like v1,v2 to it and then upload it.